# Nginx URL Rewrite Processing

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a nginx container serving static assets and if it receives a request for

https://mysite:8090/static/2.1.1/test/mystyle.css (where 2.1.1 could be any semantic version)

Nginx should serve the static assets under /usr/share/nginx/html/test/mystyle.css

I tried the following config but it did not work:

```
http {
    include    mime.types;
    sendfile on;
    server {
        server_name localhost default";
        rewrite ^.*/static/[^/]+/(.*)$ $1;
        location / {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that mean when you access `http://localhost:8090/static/2.1.1/test/mystyle.css` CSS is working fine, but with http://mysite:8090 it doesnot work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was making this more complicated than need be, didn't realize the initial slash gets dropped.

This worked for me:

```
rewrite ^/static/[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 break;
```